# The data reader is incompatible with the specified Entity Framework

Tags: c#, .net, t-sql, entity-framework-4

I have a method that will return the bare min results from a sproc to fill a select menu. When I want the bare min results I pass bool getMin = true to the sproc, and when I want the complete record I pass bool getMin = false.

This is causing the Entity FrameWork error of "**The data reader is incompatible with the specified**"

**The most relevant portion of the error**

> {"Message":"An error has occurred.","ExceptionMessage":"The data reader is incompatible with the specified 'CatalogModel.proc_GetFramingSystems_Result'. A member of the type, 'FrameType', does not have a corresponding column in the data reader with the same name.","ExceptionType":"System.Data.EntityCommandExecutionException",

Obviously the error is telling me that when the data reader attempted to set the property 'FrameType' that is was not in the query results.

Now I understand the error, what I am wanting to know is that am I goning to have t split up this sql sproc into two sprocs or is there a work around for this?

**My function below**

```
public static IEnumerable<IFramingSystem> GetFramingSystems(int brandID, string frameType, string glazeMethod, bool getMin)
{
    using (CatalogEntities db = new CatalogEntities())
    {
        return db.proc_GetFramingSystems(brandID, frameType, glazeMethod, getMin).ToList<IFramingSystem>();
    };
}
```

**My TSQL below**

```sql
ALTER proc [Catelog].[proc_GetFramingSystems]
@BrandID   INT,
@FrameType VARCHAR(26),
@GlazeMethod VARCHAR(7) ='Inside',
@getMin    BIT = 0
as
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON;
IF @getMin =0
BEGIN
SELECT c.ID,c.Name,c.Descr,c.FrameType,c.isSubFrame,
       c.GlassThickness,c.GlassPosition,c.GlazingMethod,c.SillProfile
        from Catelog.Component c
WHERE c.MyType ='Frame' 
AND c.FrameType = @FrameType
AND c.GlazingMethod = @GlazeMethod
AND c.ID IN(
SELECT cp.ComponentID FROM Catelog.Part p JOIN
            Catelog.ComponentPart cp ON p.ID = cp.PartID
            WHERE p.BrandID = @BrandID
            )
            ORDER BY c.Name
END
ELSE
SELECT c.ID,c.Name,c.Descr
        from Catelog.Component c
WHERE c.MyType ='Frame' 
AND c.FrameType = @FrameType
AND c.GlazingMethod = @GlazeMethod
AND c.ID IN(
SELECT cp.ComponentID FROM Catelog.Part p JOIN
            Catelog.ComponentPart cp ON p.ID = cp.PartID
            WHERE p.BrandID = @BrandID
            )
            ORDER BY c.Name
SET NOCOUNT OFF;
END;
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Incompatible Data Reader Exception From EF Mapped Objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14235783/incompatible-data-reader-exception-from-ef-mapped-objects)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

To me it seems that both branches of the `IF` return different data, the first branch returns 9 columns where the second - only three. I believe the EF can't reflect the `IFramingSystem` from the latter. Specifically, the column `FrameType` (and 5 other columns) are obviously missing:

```
 ...
 SELECT c.ID,c.Name,c.Descr    <- where are the remaining columns
    from Catelog.Component c
 ...
```

Comment: That is what I was thinking. Oh well, at least it was worth asking. Thank you for your help @Wiktor Zychla.

Answer (score 14):

I understand this is an old post; but, I wanted to share what I learned tonight about this.  What I found that the 'most relevant portion of the error message is stating' is this.

```
db.proc_GetFramingSystems(brandID, frameType, glazeMethod, getMin).ToList<IFramingSystem>();
```

is expecting a column to be returned from the stored procedure with the alias of 'FrameType'.

I ran into this when I created a POCO (plain old clr object) class of my table with more programmer friendly names.  Instead of a strongly typed name of say 'email_address', I wanted 'EmailAddy' and so forth.  I created a mapped class stating this among other mapped columns.

```
this.Property(t => t.EmailAddy).HasColumnName("email_address");
```

Although this is necessary for other parts of EF to work, the mapping class is not referenced when executing a db.SqlQuery.

So, when the code below executes

```
var a = new SqlParameter("@fshipno", shipno);
return _context.db.SqlQuery<EmailList>("exec spGetEmailAddy @fshipno", a).ToList();
```

It generated the same error except instead of 'FrameType', it mentioned 'EmailAddy'.

The fix... I had to alias the 'email_address' column in my stored procedure to 'EmailAddy' to get it to map the returned dataset to my POCO.

EDIT: I have found that this only works if your method is returning an `IEnumerable`:

```
public IEnumerable<myPOCO> GetMyPoco()
```

You will get the same error message if you are attempting to return a single POCO object.

```
public myPOCO GetMyPoco()
```

Answer (score 3):

If you are inserting/deleting/updating (these are considered by EF as 'non-query'), and can be called by our code using

```
MyDbContext.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(insert into Table (Col1,Col2) values (1,2));
```

But if are doing select query for a raw SQL statement, then use

```
MyDbContext.DbSet<Table_name>.SqlQuery(select * from table_name).ToList();
```

or

```
MyDbContext.Database.SqlQuery(select * from table_name).ToList();
```

()

The `SqlQuery()` function, in EF, for strange reasons, throw exception Insert/delete/update operation. (The exception thrown is "A member of the type, does not have a corresponding column in the data reader with the same name.") But it has actually performed operation if you open your Sql Management Studio and check for the entries.

FYI http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/EntityFramework4.3/raw-sql-query-in-entity-framework.aspx