# 'System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityCommandExecutionException' occurred in EntityFramework.SqlServer.dll but was not handled in user code

Tags: asp.net-mvc, datareader, ef-database-first, rawsql

I did raw SQL query below to select only certain fields from a table.

```
{
 List<CustEmpVM> CustomerVMlist = new List<CustEmpVM>();
 var cid = db.Customers.SqlQuery("select SchedDate from Customer where CustID = '@id'").ToList<Customer>();
}
```

But i keep getting the error of:
`System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityCommandExecutionException` occurred in *EntityFramework.SqlServer.dll* but was not handled in user code

> Additional information: The data reader is incompatible with the specified `ALFHomeMovers.Customer`. A member of the type, `CustID`, does not have a corresponding column in the data reader with the same name.

Comment: Is there a `CustID` column in the database?

Comment: Yes, there is @OJ Raqueno

Comment: When I checked the InnerException of that error it says that it is null. I tried applying the answers I saw with this same question but it won't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The exception message is pretty straightforward: the query expected to return full entity of `Customer` table but only `SchedDate` column returned, hence EF cannot done mapping other omitted columns including `CustID`.

Assuming `Customers` is a `DbSet<Customer>`, try return all fields from `Customer` instead:

```
// don't forget to include SqlParameter
var cid = db.Customers.SqlQuery("SELECT * FROM Customer WHERE CustID = @id", 
                                new SqlParameter("id", "[customer_id]")).ToList();
```

If you want just returning `SchedDate` column, materialize query results and use `Select` afterwards:

```
var cid = db.Customers.SqlQuery("SELECT * FROM Customer WHERE CustID = @id", 
                                new SqlParameter("id", "[customer_id]"))
                      .AsEnumerable().Select(x => x.SchedDate).ToList();
```

NB: I think you can construct LINQ based from the SELECT query above:

```
var cid = (from c in db.Customers
           where c.CustID == "[customer_id]"
           select c.SchedDate).ToList();
```

Similar issue:

[The data reader is incompatible with the specified Entity Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18791037/the-data-reader-is-incompatible-with-the-specified-entity-framework)

Answer (score 0):

Use below query instead of raw query:

```
{
 List<CustEmpVM> CustomerVMlist = new List<CustEmpVM>();
 var cid = db.Customers.Where(w=>w.Id == YOURCUSTOMERID).Select(s=>new Customer{SchedDate = s.SchedDate }).ToList();
}
```

It will give compile time error rather than run time error.