# The data reader is incompatible with the specified

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, visual-studio-2012, razor, datareader

I am inserting Data in MVC 4 using Code first approach, but, i need to upload a file and save it's name using store procedure, 
 Problem is that, data is successfully saved in database but every time, screen shows this error

Controller MEthod code is:

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult myFile(HttpPostedFileBase file, String fileName )
    {

        if (file.ContentLength > 0) 
           {

               fileName = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
               string ext = Path.GetExtension(fileName).ToLower();


            if (ext == ".jpg" || ext == ".jpeg" || ext == ".png" || ext == ".gif")
            {
                if (file.ContentLength > 0.2 * 1024 * 1024)
                { 
                    ViewBag.uploadFailMessage = "Invalid File Size, It must be less than 1 MB";
                }
                else
                {
                    var path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/uploads"),fileName);
                    file.SaveAs(path);

                          // Saving in DB
                            DBClass db = new DBClass();
                            //var postfrm = db.myFile.Add(upload);
                            //var postForm = db.myFile.Add(filee);         
                    var postForm = (myFile)db.Database.SqlQuery<myFile>("uploadSP @fileName",
                            new SqlParameter("fileName",fileName) 
                             ).FirstOrDefault();  
                          // /Saving in DB
                    ViewBag.uploadSuccessMessage = "File uploaded Succesfully"; 
                }  
            }
            else { ViewBag.uploadFailMessage = "Invalid File"; } 
          }


        return View(); 

    }
```

Model Code:

```
namespace MyBook.Models {
public class myFile
{
    [Key]
    public Int64 fileId { get; set; }
    public String fileName { get; set; }
}}
```

[image]

Comment: Look at your "uploadSP" and make sure it's returning a fileId.

Comment: possible duplicate of [The data reader is incompatible . A member does not have a corresponding column in the data reader with the same name](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14235783/the-data-reader-is-incompatible-a-member-does-not-have-a-corresponding-column)

Comment: store procedure should return a field or should not ?? please explain this.

Comment: It should return two columns - a fileId and fileName so that it can be mapped to your myFile entity.

Comment: can you give code example of store procedure which returns two fields