# Incompatible Data Reader type while using Entity Framework for Multiple Tables

Tags: c#, entity-framework

In my Model I am getting following error:

> The data reader is incompatible with the specified 'RMA.DAL.RMAs'. A member of the type, 
>   'Notes', does not have a corresponding column in the data reader with the same name.

I am using Model-View-Controller 3. Code Files given below:

**RMAModel.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using RMA.DAL;
using System.Collections;

namespace RMA.Models
{
    public class RMAs
    {
        [Key]
        public int RMANumber { get; set; }
        public int OrderNumber { get; set; }
        public string Status { get; set; }
        public int CartID { get; set; }
        public DateTime DateIssued { get; set; }
        public DateTime OrderDate { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string SKU { get; set; }
        public int QuantityAuthorized { get; set; }
        //to allow Nullable
        public int? SourceOrderNumber { get; set; }

        //For Notes
        public string Notes { get; set; }

        private DBContext_Model db = new DBContext_Model();

        public IEnumerable all()
        {
            string query = @"  SELECT DISTINCT r.RMAnumber,r.OrderNumber,r.Status,O.CartID,r.DateIssued,O.OrderDate,O.Name,oDetails.SKU,details.QuantityAuthorized,O.SourceOrderNumber,PO.PONumber
                                FROM RMAs r
                                INNER JOIN RMADetails details ON r.RMAnumber = details.RMAnumber
                                INNER  JOIN  Orders O ON O.OrderNumber = R.OrderNumber 
                                INNER  JOIN [Order Details] oDetails on O.OrderNumber = oDetails.OrderNumber
                                INNER JOIN Notes n on n.NumericKey = O.OrderNumber
                                INNER JOIN PurchaseOrders PO ON PO.OrderNumber = O.OrderNumber
                                INNER JOIN PurchaseOrderDetails PODetails ON PODetails.PONumber = PO.PONumber
                            ";
            var items = db.RMAs.SqlQuery(query);
            return items.ToList();
        }

        public IEnumerable single(int RMANumber, int OrderNumber)
        {
            string query = @"  SELECT DISTINCT r.RMAnumber,r.OrderNumber,r.Status,O.CartID,r.DateIssued,O.OrderDate,O.Name,oDetails.SKU,details.QuantityAuthorized,O.SourceOrderNumber,PO.PONumber
                                FROM RMAs r
                                INNER JOIN RMADetails details ON r.RMAnumber = details.RMAnumber
                                INNER  JOIN  Orders O ON O.OrderNumber = R.OrderNumber 
                                INNER  JOIN [Order Details] oDetails on O.OrderNumber = oDetails.OrderNumber
                                INNER JOIN Notes n on n.NumericKey = O.OrderNumber
                                INNER JOIN PurchaseOrders PO ON PO.OrderNumber = O.OrderNumber
                                INNER JOIN PurchaseOrderDetails PODetails ON PODetails.PONumber = PO.PONumber
                                AND O.OrderNumber = " + OrderNumber + " AND r.RMAnumber = " + RMANumber;
            var items = db.RMAs.SqlQuery(query);
            return items.ToList();
        }

        public IEnumerable getNotesByOrder(int OrderNumber)
        {
            string query = "Select * FROM Notes WHERE NumericKey = " + OrderNumber;
            var notes = db.Notes.SqlQuery(query);
            return notes.ToList();
        }
    }
}
```

**DAL/DBContextModel.cs**

```
using System.Data.Entity; 
using RMA.Models;

namespace RMA.DAL
{
    public class DBContext_Model:DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<RMAs> RMAs { get; set; }
        public DbSet<RMADetails> RMADetails { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Note> Notes { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**DetailsController.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using RMA.Models;
using System.Collections;

namespace RMA.Controllers
{
    public class DetailsController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult Index(int id, int orderid)
        {
            RMAs modelRMA = new RMAs();
            IEnumerable singleRMA = modelRMA.single(id,orderid);
            IEnumerable notes = modelRMA.getNotesByOrder(orderid);
            ViewBag.notes = notes;
            return View(singleRMA);
        }

    }
}
```

**index.cshtml**

```
@model IEnumerable<RMA.Models.RMAs>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Details Page";
}
<style>
    #overview
    {
        width: 100%;
        height:40%;
    }
    div > table
    {
        width:100%;
    }
    #notes
    {
        margin-top:2%;
    }
    .left
    {
        width:40%;
        margin-top:5%;
        background-color:Blue;
        color:White;
    }
</style>
<h4>Summary</h4>
<div id=overview>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>Order #</th>
            <th>RMA #</th>
            <th>RMA Status</th>
            <th>Market Place ID</th>
            <th>RMA Issue Date</th>
            <th>Order Date</th>
            <th>Cust Ship To Name</th>
            <th>Local Sku</th>
            <th>RMA Qty</th>
            <th>Marketplace Order #</th>
        </tr>
         @foreach (RMA.Models.RMAs i in Model)
        {
            //<span>@i.OrderNumber</span>
            <tr>
                <td>@i.OrderNumber</td>
                <td>@i.RMANumber</td>
                <td>@i.Status</td>
                <td>@i.CartID</td>
                <td>@i.DateIssued</td>
                <td>@i.OrderDate</td>
                <td>@i.Name</td>
                <td>@i.SKU</td>
                <td>@i.QuantityAuthorized</td>
                <td>@i.SourceOrderNumber</td>
            </tr>
        }
    </table>
</div>
<h4>Notes</h4>
<div id=notes>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>Notes</th>
            <th>Date</th>
            <th>Time</th>

        </tr>
        @foreach (IEnumerable<RMA.Models.RMAs> note in @ViewBag.notes)
        {
        <tr>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        }
    </table>
</div>
<div class=left>
    My Reason Goes here
</div>
<div class=left>
    Shipping Info
</div>
<div class=left>
    Billing Info
</div>
```

I want to how `Notes` table Data on MyView.

Comment: Why these query strings, why don't you have LINQ statements?

Comment: I am new to asp.net/mvc3 and I don't know LINQ

Comment: Then learning LINQ should be prio 1 for you! Spend the next few days doing nothing but that. It's going to give you the highest ROI ever. Entity Framework without LINQ is like a car without gas.

Comment: This is not the solution. You are suggesting that EF can't work without LINQ while it can. Anyways thanks for your time

Comment: Of course it's not a direct solution, but you really shouldn't go on like this. That's nothing but a sincere advice. The cause of the error is that the `SELECT` list doesn't match RMAs properties, `Notes` is not in it. But do yourself a big favor and try to fix it by writing LINQ.

Comment: While I see that you asked for my help on the other question, I have to echo @GertArnold here. Yes, what you're trying to do is *possible*, but it is not an idiomatic use of EF. If you truly want to write your own SQL--and plenty of people do--you're much better off creating stored procedures and mapping them to entities. That said, the issue is that you aren't bringing back a "Notes" column to map to the entity.