# does not have a corresponding column in the data reader with the same name

Tags: entity-framework

I have `Table` named `tbl_search` with columns : `id(int), title(nvarchar100), result(ntext)`
and i want using `SQL query`, like this :

```
    using (var db = new GoogleEntities())
      {
          const string selectCmd =
                @"Select top 1 title From tbl_search Where title=@title and id=@id ";

         var data = db.Database.SqlQuery<tbl_search>(
                selectCmd,
                new SqlParameter("@title", "wcf"),
                new SqlParameter("@id", 1)
                ).FirstOrDefault();



           if (data != null)
               {
                var serviceMember = data.ToString();
                label1.Text = serviceMember == "" ? "" : (serviceMember == "True" ? "On" : "Off");
               }
       }
```

but it give me an error :

> The data reader is incompatible with the specified 'GoogleModel.tbl_search'. A member of the type, 'id', does not have a corresponding column in the data reader with the same name.

NOTE: this is my `tbl_search` class :

```
 public partial class tbl_search
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string title { get; set; }
    public string result { get; set; }
}
```

i have `id` in my table.. What is the problem!!

Comment: Show your `tbl_search` class.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Incompatible Data Reader Exception From EF Mapped Objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14235783/incompatible-data-reader-exception-from-ef-mapped-objects)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Your SQL Statement only returns the title not the full entity.

Change:

```
Select top 1 title From tbl_search Where title=@title and id=@id
```

to:

```
Select top 1 * From tbl_search Where title=@title and id=@id
```

Comment: @codewrox i dont need id, is therre any way to do this without this way?

Comment: I had this issue, i used dapper, db.Database.Connection.Query extension, instead of db.Database.SqlQuery.

Comment: This solved my problem, thanks!, i would recommend to use columns names instead (*). Using (*) is a bad practice.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue because I had a '@StartDate' in my last select and asp.net could not read it and returned it as 'Column1', so I have solved this by assigning @StartDate to a variable which is good practice anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Please check the connection string in the `web.config`(Check if you are connected to correct domain).

In my case - my database connection string in `web.config` was referring to QA and I was modifying in Dev database.

Answer (score 0):

I did the following:

1. Verified that the stored procedure was up-to-date (the "live" columns were updated).
2. In EF, I removed, saved, then re-added the stored proc.
3. Rebuilt and verified all of the types were mapped correctly (no errors).

After doing the above, the error was gone.