# error in entity frame work

Tags: sql, entity-framework-4

I Write A SQl Query In Entity Frame Work

```
var query1 = database.Database.SqlQuery<customer>("select name from customer where shomaremoshtare ='" + txt_shomaremoshtare.Text.Trim() + "'");
```

When I Run This Code I Give This Error
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yxNG6.png)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [does not have a corresponding column in the data reader with the same name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24732320/does-not-have-a-corresponding-column-in-the-data-reader-with-the-same-name)

Answer (score 1):

You are returning only the name of the entity in your select, try to return all the fields like this:

```
var query1 = database.Database.SqlQuery<customer>("select * from customer where shomaremoshtare ='" + txt_shomaremoshtare.Text.Trim() + "'");
```

The type expected is customer not just a name.