# System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityCommandExecutionException occurred in EntityFramework.SqlServer.dll but was not handled in user code

Tags: asp.net-mvc

```
namespace EmployeeDemo.Controllers
{
    public class EmployeeController : Controller
    {
        // GET: Employee
        public ActionResult Details(int id)
        {
            EmployeeContext employeeContext = new EmployeeContext();
            Employee employee =
                      employeeContext.Employees.Single(emp => emp.ID== id);
            return View(employee);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: can any help me out ..i just want to display employee details based on id.i have tried to change in web.config but i was unable to solve.i have used code first  model

Comment: First, you should use SingleOrDefault in case the employee ID does not exist (especially being passed as a parameter - could be anything). Second, a few things may be wrong: your connection string, the EF table configuration. Is that database and tables created properly?

Comment: <add name="EmployeeContext"
          connectionString="server=.; database=TrainingDB; integrated security=SSPI"
          providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>

Comment: i have used one table only, and i created new application but i am getting same kind of exception

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31118257/system-data-entity-core-entitycommandexecutionexception-occurred-in-mvc-app-usin