# Only assignment, call, increment, decrement, and new object expressions can be used as a statement error when no error(Closed)

Tags: c#, asp.net, database

Im getting these two errors,
1.Only assignment, call, increment, decrement, and new object expressions can be used as a statement 
2.; Expected

```
 protected bool IsPatientAlreadyExists(String patientId)
    {
        using (CareGiverEntities dc = new CareGiverEntities())
        {

             dc.Contacts.Add(new Contact
            {
               return dc.Contacts.Any(x=> x.PatientIc==patientId);
            });
        }
        return false;

    }
```

i really cant see whats wrong with these codes hoping someone can enlighten me

Comment: It seems you copy/pasted something and did not clean up: guessing from your method's name, remove `dc.Contacts.Add(new Contact {` You only want to keep this line: `return dc.Contacts.Any(x => x.PatientId == patientId);`

Comment: @RenéVogt look at the name of the function

Comment: You can't use `dc.Contacts.Add(new Contact)` line with `return` keyword inside.

Comment: @galister what do you mean? Note that your answer is the same as my comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
dc.Contacts.Add(new Contact
{
    return dc.Contacts.Any(x => x.PatientIc == patientId);
});
```

You create `Contact` object but use `return` statement in object initializer.

Change your `using` to:

```
using (CareGiverEntities dc = new CareGiverEntities())
{
    return dc.Contacts.Any(x => x.PatientIc == patientId);
}
```

Comment: @Thibaut, what does it mean? Could you explain a little more?

Comment: An exception of type 'System.Data.EntityCommandExecutionException' occurred in System.Data.Entity.dll but was not handled in user codes

Comment: @Thibaut, is database created? Are there pending migrations?

Comment: maybe u can refer to my original thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42062443/prevent-multiple-duplicate-data-entry-into-entities-database

Comment: @Thibaut, have you fixed the problem with exception?