# Visual studio 2017 output window entity framwork exception

Tags: visual-studio-2017

Why am I getting this in the output window:
Exception thrown: 'System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityCommandExecutionException' in EntityFramework.SqlServer.dll

Is there any way to see where the exception is thrown from and why this is ?

Comment: Did you consider this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31118257/system-data-entity-core-entitycommandexecutionexception-occurred-in-mvc-app-usin and if so, why didnt you mention it in your question?

Comment: Delete try/catch from the code first, don't put it back until you figured out how to handle the exception.  If that doesn't help then use the debugger.  Debug > Windows > Exception Settings, tick the box for CLR exceptions.  The stack trace shows which statement failed.

Answer (score 1):

Debug > Windows > Exception Settings, tick the box for CLR exceptions was what I was looking for.