# How do you add connection string web.config for multi active result set in asp.net visual studio 2017

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

i am having error when populating data System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityCommandExecutionException: 'An error occurred while executing the command definition. See the inner exception for details.'

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="DefaultConnections"      
    connectionString="Data Source= 
   (LocalDb)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnet- 
    XEx20UserMaintenance-20160725031209.mdf;
    Initial Catalog=aspnet-XEx20UserMaintenance-20160725031209;
    Integrated Security=True;
    MultipleActiveResultSets=True;"
  providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
    </connectionStrings>
```

[server image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/78NSP.png)

Answer (score 1):

Sorry can't leave it as a comment as i don't have 50 reputations, check this out

[System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityCommandExecutionException Occurred in MVC app Using EF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31118257/system-data-entity-core-entitycommandexecutionexception-occurred-in-mvc-app-usin)